# How do I model line comments in a CFG?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

Assume we want to define a context free grammar of say a programming language, where on each line everything after the character # until the end of line is considered a comment and should be ignored. How to express that in a context free grammar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can just treat comments as whitespaces.

Answer (score 3):

Without multi-line statements, it's rather simple; assuming `line` is the non-terminal for well-formed line, change its right-hand-side appearances to

```
line (# .*)?
```

(borrowing regular expression syntax for brevity).

Otherwise, if you explicitly handle line breaks, replace occurrences of the line-break token `CRLF` (or so) similarly by

```
(# .*)? CRLF
```

If line breaks remain implicit, one chance you have left is make it part of the lexer; don't only skip whitepace, but also `(# .*)? [\r\n]`. You can also create a token `COMMENT` for that and place it in all places of the grammar where it may appear. This strategy doesn't work for nested multiline comments, though, a common problem in older languages.

Comment: thanks, sorry but I don't fully understand the syntax you're using. also I have to do it all using a context free grammar, even if I rely on a lexer, the lexer has to be expressed as a cfg as well. and unfortunately I have to support multiline statements that may contain comments each, just like // in C (btw I see that C lexer also had to do it using some kind of "hack" as in here http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html )

Comment: @TroyMcClure Are you a student facing an exercise task, or are you a practitioner traying to build a compiler?

Comment: The first two approaches should be workable given the setting you describe. Note that, in practice, such issues are probably often taken care of by some preprocessing -- it's trivial to run a tool over a a set of files that removes all comment suffices from lines (unless your language has stuff like multi-line strings, you are interested in extracting the content of some comments, or any number of other complications, of course). Then you don't have to handle them in your grammar.

Comment: @troy: the link you provide a quote is not "the C lexer", but rather a lexer put together by someone, not as part of any C compiler. Furthermore, it does not recognise line comments, which as  Raphael says, are trivial, but rather C's multiline comment syntax. (This can also be represented as a regular expression, and you should be able to find a correct one easily enough a or with a little more thought write one.) The hack in the code snippet was probably pragmatic with lex, but flex works much better with regular expressions and any serious C implementation would use one.

Comment: @Troy: anyway, you "model" a comment just like you model whitespace. In almost all languages, they're syntactically and semantically identical.

Comment: @rici yes i figured it out in the meanwhile, i'll just treat it as space indeed